# How to write sql statement comparison

Tags: postgresql

the query statement gets result Tom and Alex, who write more book than magazine.
How can I write sql statement to realize?
Thanks.

Comment: What did you try? What issues did you experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL:

```
SELECT ac.author, COUNT(b.*) AS number_of_books, COUNT(m.*) AS number_of_magazine 
FROM AuthorCollection ac
LEFT JOIN book b ON b.key = ac.key
LEFT JOIN magazine m ON m.key = ac.key 
GROUP BY ac.author;
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHHo6.png)

Below sql will give you exact result,

```
SELECT foo.author FROM (
SELECT ac.author, COUNT(b.*) AS number_of_books, COUNT(m.*) AS number_of_magazine 
FROM AuthorCollection ac
LEFT JOIN book b ON b.key = ac.key
LEFT JOIN magazine m ON m.key = ac.key 
GROUP BY ac.author
HAVING COUNT(b.*) > COUNT(m.*)
) foo;
```

Comment: Thanks!!! I just begin to learn sql, and I always have a problem to understand COUNT(). I know the gramma of COUNT(), but I cannot understand why COUNT(b.*) and COUNT(m.*) works for this problem, Can you explain more about COUNT()? How can you write it correctly? Thanks!!!